# How to filter index for true value in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to filter database index list by whether or not a value is true. Is this possible? Within the controller I am attempting this, which is not resolving to an error, but does not pull the index list I am looking for.

Controller:

```
def index
        @people = Person.all

        if params[:filter_by]
            @people = Person.where(:position => params[:filter_by])
        elsif 
            @people = Person.where(:ra_cs, params[:filter_by] == "true")
        else
            @people = Person.all
        end
    end 

def person_params
        params.require(:person).permit(
            :fname, :lname, :user_name, :position, :title, :prefix, :focus1, :focus2, :focus3, :ra_cs, :ra_hn, :ra_mg, :ra_nb, :ra_ne) 
    end
```

The entry for the database is a checkbox, which inputs a value of 1 or 0 into the field.

I am not sure what other code might be involved, please let me know if I need to add anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refactor your code:

```rb
def index
  if params[:filter_by].present?
    case params[:filter_by]
    when 'ra_cs'
      @people = Person.where(ra_cs: true)
    when 'ra_aa'
      @people = Person.where(ra_aa: true)
    when 'ra_bb'
      @people = Person.where(ra_bb: true)
    else
      @people = Person.where(position: params[:filter_by])
    end
  else
    @people = Person.all
  end
end
```

Btw, `elsif` needs a condition.

Comment: I tried this code, but it is still not showing anything in the filtered page. All of my older filters still work, but the ra_cs filter still gives me nothing in the list. I tried changing the value to 1, which is what is shown in my database once the person's profile has the ra_cs box checked.

Comment: I edited the answer to fit your DB. Pls, add the value of `params` in your question.

Comment: I have added that I think you are asking for, if not, can you please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I asked for the _contents_ of `params`, actually. Check the log, or place `byebug` right after `def index`, then type `params` on the prompt.

Comment: Ah I see, what the log tell me is this: `Parameters: {"filter_by"=>"ra_cs"}
  Person Load (7.6ms)  SELECT `people`.* FROM `people` WHERE `people`.`position` = 'ra_cs'  ORDER BY lname`   The `ra_cs` is not a `person.position` variable, it is its own `person.ra_cs`

Comment: Thank worked great! Thank you so very much for your time and patience with me!

Comment: Can I ask an expansion to this? If I have 4 other ra_xx things to filter by, can I use an elsif with the code you provided to filter by each of those? Or am I over simplifying my problem?

Comment: Sure, but maybe `case` is a better option. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: That works perfectly! Is `case` a ruby thing? I feel like I am under educated in the programming side of all of this. Thank you again, I wish I could buy you a coffee!!

Comment: Yes, it is Ruby. Maybe you want to take a look at https://ruby.github.io/TryRuby/. And thanks for that coffee! :-D

Comment: @lostrennie Check out the [Ruby control expressions documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression). Which explains the *case* statement, among many others.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using dynamic `where` where parameters.

```
def index
  @people = Person.all

  @people = @people.where(params[:filter_by] => true) if params[:filter_by].present?
end
```

If you don't what the user filtering by every attribute you could add a whitelist.

```
def index
  @people = Person.all

  allowed = %w[ra_cs ra_aa ra_bb ...]
  @people = @people.where(params[:filter_by] => true) if params[:filter_by].in?(allowed)
end
```

In this second example you don't have to check for the presence, since `nil` or `""` would be returned, which is not in `allowed`. Meaning that the *if*-statement would evaluate to `false` anyway.

Comment: If you're wondering what `%w[...]` is, have a look at the [percent literal documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings).

Comment: This looks great! Once I have a usable version of this live, I will come back to this and check it out, as my people are always wanting new ways to filter the list. Thanks!! Hopefully you do not mind me resurrecting this in a couple of weeks with questions!